# What is the Umlaut Symbol in this relay?

Tags: switches, normally-open

I'm wondering if the reoccurring "Umlaut" (Ö) symbol in a manual for a process controller that I'm referencing is an actual electronic representation of something, if so what, or if this process control manual was translated from German and was meant as just an "O" symbol? The diagram shows a voltage dependent varisistor relay might the "Ö" represent N.O. terminal? Thanks for the Help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgwb5p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: S: *Schließer*, literally "closer" (N.O), Ö: *Öffner* literally "opener" (N.C.) S and Ö are mixed up in your drawing.

Comment: The umlaut (and words Schließer and Öffner) are from the German language.

Comment: Thanks! What might P=

Comment: P – Phase (live wire). This is the old naming scheme. Today it should be marked L.

Comment: Great thanks for the help I'm learning these things without any formal training. I appreciate the clarification and resource!

Comment: From comments and responses have I represented the Line and switching terminations correctly?

Comment: Thank you Janka! I missed that!